# Getting a "NoMethodError in Boards#show" error when going to #new action (not trying to access a method, and the variable exists)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm very new to Ruby on Rails, so forgive if this is a stupid mistake.

I used a rails generate scaffold command to generate a "board" scaffold with a title:string and message:text. Now, I'm trying to go to localhost:3000/boards/new and I'm getting a "NoMethodError in Boards#show" error when I try to access board.message. I don't get any error when I try to access board.title.

Code:

*form.html.erb*

```
<%= form_for(@board) do |f| %>
  <% if @board.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@board.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this board from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @board.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :title %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :title %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :message %><br />
    <%= f.text_area :message %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I'm specifically getting the error on line 20 (<%= f.text_area :message %>)

*board.rb*

```
class Board < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :message, :title
  has_many :posts
end
```

*boards_controller.rb*

```
class BoardsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /boards
  # GET /boards.json
  def index
    @boards = Board.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @boards }
    end
  end

  # GET /boards/1
  # GET /boards/1.json
  def show
    @board = Board.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @board }
    end
  end

  # GET /boards/new
  # GET /boards/new.json
  def new
    @board = Board.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @board }
    end
  end

  # GET /boards/1/edit
  def edit
    @board = Board.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /boards
  # POST /boards.json
  def create
    @board = Board.new(params[:board])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @board.save
        format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @board, status: :created, location: @board }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /boards/1
  # PUT /boards/1.json
  def update
    @board = Board.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @board.update_attributes(params[:board])
        format.html { redirect_to @board, notice: 'Board was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @board.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /boards/1
  # DELETE /boards/1.json
  def destroy
    @board = Board.find(params[:id])
    @board.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to boards_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

*routes.rb*

```
Anonymous::Application.routes.draw do

  resources :boards


  resources :posts

  root :to => "boards#index"

end
```

Can anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: can you post your controller and routes?

Comment: I would check your database, maybe you have a pending migration, can you confirm your `boards` table has `message` column?

Comment: ok that worked. I had to manually drop the "boards" table before I did 'rake db:migrate'. i had a 'boards' table before that did not have the message column, so when I was doing 'rake db:migrate' it wasn't running (because boards already existed)